# Is there an OSGI container for californium like how Kura is for MQTT ? Or can kura be configured for californium?

Tags: java, osgi, paho, kura

Is there  an OSGI container for californium like how Kura is for MQTT ? Or can kura be configured for californium? I am currently using kura for my MQTT based application and I want to know if I can copy over the source code that interacts with the hardware and just adjust the libraries.

Comment: What kind of container are you looking for? Californium appears to be provided as OSGi bundles, so I assume it would work in at least Equinox and probably other OSGi Frameworks also.

Answer (score 1):

You can find californium-osgi bundle in [their maven repository](http://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.eclipse.californium/californium-osgi).
The version of californium-osgi I use is **1.0.3**, and for kura is **1.4.0**.

1. Choose a version you like in the maven repository, and get the link of bundle.
2. Log into OSGi console and enter `install -start "the link your just copied"`

Then you will see it successfully activated!
Hope this solve your problem.

[Screenshot here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/qIGHx.png)